# JSON to XML conversion without changing the sequence

Tags: java, json, xml

I am using the below code to convert json to xml of multiple XML files with different JSON structures.

```
String toXmlRequest = fullRequest.toString();               
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(toXmlRequest);              
String XmlRequest = XML.toString(jsonObj);
System.out.println(XmlRequest);
```

**Input**

```
     {
      "EnrollmentRequest":
        {
          "data": 
            {
              "commonDataContext":
                   {
                      "requestId": "ADA12131",
                      "clientId": "ABCDEF",
                      "timestamp":"2013-12-13T11:10:00.715-05:00"
                   },
               "cardNumber" : "123456789012345" ,
               "firstName" : "John" ,
               "lastName" : "Smith" ,
               "email" : "JohnSmith@g.com" ,
               "enrollStatus" : "E" , 
               "pathEnroll" : "NewAcct",
               "cardSavedIndicator" : "Y"
          }
        }
     }
```

**Output**

```
      <EnrollmentRequest>
          <data>
              <firstName>John</firstName>
              <lastName>Smith</lastName>
              <commonDataContext>
                    <clientId>ABCDEF</clientId>
                    <requestId>ADA12131</requestId>
                    <timestamp>2013-12-13T11:10:00.715-05:00</timestamp>
              </commonDataContext>
              <pathEnroll>NewAcct</pathEnroll>
              <enrollStatus>E</enrollStatus>
              <cardSavedIndicator>Y</cardSavedIndicator>
              <cardNumber>123456789012345</cardNumber>
              <email>JohnSmith@g.com</email>
          </data>
      </EnrollmentRequest>
```

The sequence of the output is getting changed. It is not able to keep the actual sequence. Is there any way this can be kept intact.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: why does you need to keep in the same order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using `org.json.JSONObject` directly. The reason is that JSONObject uses an internal store of type HashMap. HashMap does not preserve insertion order

It would be possible with a `LinkedHashMap`, however it does not appear possible to configure JSONObject to use one.

```
/**
 * Construct an empty JSONObject.
 */
public JSONObject() {
    this.map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
}
```

An alternative would be to read using a library that does preserve order, e.g. Jackson....

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jackson = mapper.readTree(fullRequest);
```

and then feed that into XML

```
String xmlRequest = XML.toString(new JSONAdapter(jackson));
```

with the necessary type adaption to make the Jackson object look like a org.json.JSONObject. Incomplete example below:

```
private static class JSONAdapter extends JSONObject {

    private JsonNode jackson;

    public JSONAdapter(JsonNode jackson) {
        this.jackson = jackson;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> keys() {
        return jackson.fieldNames();
    }

    @Override
    public Object opt(String key) {
        return get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String key) throws JSONException {
        JsonNode nested = jackson.get(key);
        if (nested.isObject()) {
            return new JSONAdapter(nested);
        } else if (nested.isTextual()) {
            return nested.asText();
        } else if (nested.isNumber()) {
            return nested.asDouble();
        } else if (nested.isBoolean()) {
            return nested.asBoolean();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Output

```
<EnrollmentRequest>
    <data>
        <commonDataContext>
            <requestId>ADA12131</requestId>
            <clientId>ABCDEF</clientId>
            <timestamp>2013-12-13T11:10:00.715-05:00</timestamp>
        </commonDataContext>
        <cardNumber>123456789012345</cardNumber>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Smith</lastName>
        <email>JohnSmith@g.com</email>
        <enrollStatus>E</enrollStatus>
        <pathEnroll>NewAcct</pathEnroll>
        <cardSavedIndicator>Y</cardSavedIndicator>
    </data>
</EnrollmentRequest>
```

Comment: This is not working on your embedded Json Arrays. I am getting my embedded arrays as blank in xml.

Answer (score 0):

For embedded json arrays, you need to apply one more condition to check if it array and return it as json array.

```
if(nested.isArray()) {
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
            for(JsonNode value : nested){
                arr.put(value.asText());
            }
            return arr;
        }
```